# Golang. How to save kerberos TGT to cache?

Tags: go, kerberos

I trying to get a Kerberos TGT using the gokrb5 library (https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5)

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8/client"
    "github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8/config"
)

func main() {

    cfg, _ := config.Load("./krb5.conf")

    cl := client.NewWithPassword("admin", "TEST.DOMAIN", "12345678", cfg)

    err := cl.Login()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error on logging in with KDC : %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

This code sends a request to the KDC but doesn't store the TGT in the cache.

I couldn't find the answer in the project documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8)
Maybe someone knows how to do it?
thanks in advance)